# Using decorators in python to build a complex composite class from a set of simple component classes

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, decorator

I am using the decorator design pattern to build a "composite class" that composes together the behavior of a set of "component classes". The behavior of the relevant method from each component class is governed by a dictionary *param_dict*, so that each component class has its own *param_dict*. The composite class also has a *composite_param_dict*, which is successively built up from the component dictionaries.

The behavior I need is the following: when an instance of the composite class has a value of *composite_param_dict* changed, I need the behavior of the inherited method to change.

Here is a minimal example of my class design:

```
class Component(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.param_dict = {'a':4}

    def component_method(self, x):
        return self.param_dict['a']*x
```

I pass an instance of Component to the Composite constructor:

```
class Composite(object):

    def __init__(self, instance):

        self.instance = instance

        # In the following line of code, 
        # I use copy to emphasize that there actually multiple 
        # instance.param_dict that are being passed to init, 
        # so composite_param_dict is not simply a reference
        self.composite_param_dict = copy(self.instance.param_dict)

        setattr(self, 'composite_method', self.param_dict_decorator(getattr(self.instance, 'component_method')))

    def param_dict_decorator(self, func):

        self.instance.param_dict['a'] = self.composite_param_dict['a']
        return func
```

For the sake of being concise in this example, there is only one component, but in general there are many, so in general *composite_param_dict* has many keys, and the composite class has many inherited methods.

Additionally, I need to use *getattr* and *setattr* because I will not necessarily know in advance what the names of the methods I will need to inherit are. In general, the component models will tell the composite model which methods to inherit, so I cannot hard-code the method names into the composite model. In this minimal example, for the sake of being concise, I have gone ahead and hard-coded the method name *component_method*, and suppressed the mechanism by which this information is transmitted.

I build my composite class as follows:

```
component_instance = Component()
composite_instance = Composite(component_instance)
```

With my decorator written as I have in the above example, changes in the *composite_param_dict* do **not** propagate correctly, but I do not understand why not. For example:

```
composite_instance.composite_param_dict['a'] = 10
print composite_instance.composite_method(10)
40
```

If the values of *composite_param_dict* were correctly propagating, then the correct answer should be 100.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use metaclasses instead?

Comment: Sure, simple reason: I don't know how. What would the class design be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only call `param_dict_decorator` once, at the moment when you create the `composite_method`.  It is not called again every time you call the composite method.  So it effectively "freezes" `self.instance.param_dict` with the value present in `self.composite_param_dict` at the time when you create the composite object.

If you want custom code to run every time `composite_method` is called, you can't just return `func` from `param_dict_decorator`.  `param_dict_decorator` is only called once; it is what is *returned* from `param_dict_decorator` that you assign to `composite_method`, so that is what will be called whenever you call `composite_method`.   So you need `param_dict_decorator` to return a *new* function that incorporates the "updating" behavior.  Here's an example:

```
def param_dict_decorator(self, func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        self.instance.param_dict['a'] = self.composite_param_dict['a']
        return func(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

With this change, it works:

```
>>> composite_instance = Composite(component_instance)
>>> composite_instance.composite_method(10)
40
>>> composite_instance.composite_param_dict['a'] = 10
>>> composite_instance.composite_method(10)
100
```

More generally, the concept of decorators is that they take in a function and return a new function that is meant to replace the original function.  In your `param_dict_decorator`, you just return the original function, so your decorator has no effect at all on the behavior of `func`.

Comment: Very clear answer, BrenBarn. Pretty basic mistake on my part.